# I did localstorage.setItem() in one component and i want to do localstorage.getItem() in second component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I have 2 components in ReactJS and I did localstorage.setItem() in one component and I want to do localstorage.getItem() in second component. how should i do it. right now I did both setitem() and getItem() in the same component and passed the value of getItem using props to the second component. But I want to do getItem() in the second component is there any way to do so?

Comment: ```localstorage``` is window propert that is global , so you can access from any component where you want, set it where you need and just use ```localstorage.getItem``` to access.

Comment: Isn't localstorage a global object that you can access from any components?

Answer (score 0):

Example:
in Login component, you can set your user object/ or any field:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', user);
```

in any another component, you can access it like this:

```
let userData = localStorage.getItem('user');
```

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage is a property of the window interface. You can find more information in the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). This means that you can access it form any point of your application. Look at the below example to understand this notion.

**containerComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PresentationalComponent from './PresentationalComponent'

const containerComponent = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("hello", "hi"); // localStorage only accepts string values

    return <PresentationalComponent />
}
export default containerComponent;
```

**PresentationalComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const PresentationalComponent = () => {
    return <h1>{`The hello localStorage key has a value of ${localStorage.getItem("hello")}`}</h1>
}

export default PresentationalComponent;
```